# Some bounded theorem of algebraic stack of coherent sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks, coherent-sheaves

Let $X$ be a connected projective scheme. Let $U$ be a finite type open substack of the algebraic stack of coherent sheaves on $X$ with a fixed Hilbert polynomial. Can one take $p>0$ such that every sheaf in $U$ is Castelnuovo-Mumford $p$-regular? It seems true and used in some papers (maybe with additional condition), but I cannot show this statement. Could anyone give me a sketch of a proof?

Comment: See FGA Explained, or Mumford's book on curves on algebraic surfaces. I think you can obtain a p only depend on the hilbert polynomial. 

Comment: @temp:  There is no $p$ that depends only on the Hilbert polynomial.  To see this, consider the infinite sequence of locally free sheaves `$\mathcal{O}(-n)\oplus \mathcal{O}(n)$` on `$\mathbb{P}^1$`.  

Answer (score 3):

Lemma 1.7.6, p. 28 of the book by Huybrechts and Lehn.